# Bundling webpack alongside dotnet run

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core

I have started a .NET Core Web Api application and I'm using webpack to bundle my javascript and use ES6 features.

However, everytime I make a change and want to see it live I have to run two commands in the VS Code terminal:

1. `webpack`
2. `dotnet run`

Is there a way to consolidate these two commands into just `dotnet run` so that the webpack would get bundled automatically?

As a bonus before I put my Javascript into my web api application, I was able to use the webpack-dev-server and it would automatically run the `webpack` command whenever I made changes so I'm curious if there's any way to bundle this functionality into the above as well.

Comment: See: http://cecilphillip.com/setting-up-webpack-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @MarkPM Could you show how that would look with the new csproj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can execute any scripts as your project build or before publishing by including the script in your .csproj file. For example.

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
</Target>
```

This would install npm packages in your app before publishing.

or in your case

```
<Target Name="NpmCommands" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="webpack" />
 </Target>
```

to bundle your files after project build.